# Postgresql size of table and full join

Tags: database, postgresql, join, size

The file I am working with :

```
spark@cv-local:~$ ls -lh idUser.csv 
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres 9.5M Apr 22 14:55 idUser.csv
```

Size of my DB before :

```
spark@cv-local:/var$ sudo du -h | grep main  
5.8M   ./lib/postgresql/9.1/main/base/57371
```

Psql :

```
test2=# create table client_id (iditem INT);
CREATE TABLE
test2=# copy client_id from '/home/spark/idUser.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
COPY 1158836
```

Size of my DB after :

```
spark@cv-local:/var$ sudo du -h | grep main
46M   ./lib/postgresql/9.1/main/base/57371
```

Could someone explain me why the size is 4 times bigger on postgres than in a normal file?

I looked into that because I tried to full join ( *CREATE TABLE testjoin AS SELECT * FROM client_id, item_id;* ) two files, one of 9.5M and the other of 5.8M I got an error disk space. The database size go to through roof : from 70M to more than 60G.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your join-table, remember to specify a where clause. Otherwise your table will contain all possible combinations of entries from client_id and item_id!

Comment: It is what I am looking for ;).
My table client_id, as just one column and the same as item_id. I want to associate a client to all the items.

Answer (score 0):

1. On my machine, as part of normal operation, PostgreSQL creates 16MB file under pg_xlog - this is transaction log. This file would be empty when you just create database. However, after reaching 16MB it would stay at this size. For you, this file alone could mean almost 50% of unexpected increase.
2. It is normal that database takes slightly more space on disk than original data in text file like CSV. Database has some overhead because it has to maintain internal structures and possibly indexes. However, if you have highly compressible large text columns, PostgreSQL will automatically compress them, which might make database size smaller than original data.
3. If you perform `VACUUM FULL`, your database should shrink in size. However, this decrease will be significant only if you had a lot of deleted rows. Note that you should not normally `VACUUM FULL` as this operation locks tables exclusively. Instead, you should use simple VACUUM or just rely on an auto-vacuum.
4. For such a small size as yours - under 100MB, it is not fair to compare sizes. You should only do so after reaching into few hundred megabytes.